# Natively Find & Replace with wildcards in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, find-and-replace

Is there a way to natively use wildcards in Find & Replace, in Excel 2010?  I'd rather not install an add-on if it can be avoided.

For example: I want to be able to use a syntax similar to the following, in the Find & Replace dialog:

- **FIND:** `=IF(SUM(*)=0,"",SUM(*))`
- **REPLACE:** `=SUM(*)`

This should find a formula such as `=IF(SUM(A1:A10)=0,"",SUM(A1:A10))` and replace it with `=SUM(A1:A10)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a question mark as a wildcard in a Find or Find & Replace. If there are multiple wildcards in a row, use question mark + asterisk:

```
=IF(SUM(?*)=0,"",SUM(?*))
```

In the example above you're searching formulas, not values, so make sure you expand the Find dialog box by clicking on the "Options" button in the bottom right, and select "Formulas" in the "Look In" dropdown. Hope this helps!

Edit: This won't work for replace the way you've described. I'm not sure there's a way to do that with Find & Replace. You could do it with a VBA script though.

-- jm